# Digital Peephole Viewer

Tags: video, video-camera, home-security

I have a motion-recording camera at my front door, but when the doorbell rings, the app takes so long to come up that I'm already at the door and sometimes it just gets stuck attempting to connect (it's a Logitech Alert for the record).  I'm thinking a simple digital peephole viewer will solve the problem (no wireless/internet connection required to see the picture).  I'd like one with the following characteristics:

- at least 640x480 resolution
- turns on and shows picture in less than one second
- mounts on door only in a standard peephole-sized hole (no doorbell-style button required)
- works at least OK with backlight (I have a porch making the people poorly lit once they step up to the door)
- no cords to plug in (probably battery powered)
- Under $100 shipped (to USA)

Nice-to-haves:

- motion-detection that will automatically show the picture when movement is detected in a certain area of the frame (this may be energy-prohibitive for a battery-powered device)
- recording (SD, Wi-Fi, or App)

All the ones I've seen so far on Amazon would [replace my doorbell](http://smile.amazon.com/digitharbor-peephole-shooting-Doorbell-Security/dp/B00HFJH81I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448929182&sr=8-1&keywords=digital+peephole) (I'd like to avoid that in case the batteries die), they are [low resolution](http://smile.amazon.com/RioRand-degrees-Peephole-Doorbell-Security/dp/B00MP4J9KQ/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1448929182&sr=8-2&keywords=digital+peephole), they [don't work with bright backgrounds](http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B002QGU8D0/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=29HEG0YWROF61&coliid=I3PVBXC8L1A5SY), or some combination of all of those.

Comment: it hate to break it to you James, but i know a small camera the record video at 1080p for 50 to 100 buck but i forgot the name, but are you looking for maybe a smal dash cam thingy that you can mount on you door? if so i can try to find the name for you.